# Proving $A^n=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&(2^n-1)a\\0&2^n\end{smallmatrix}\right]$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Given the matrix
>   \begin{align}
> A = \begin{bmatrix}1&a\\0&2\end{bmatrix} ,
> \end{align}
>   is it true that
>   \begin{align}
> A^n=\begin{bmatrix}1&(2^n-1)a\\0&2^n\end{bmatrix}
> \end{align}
>   for all $n \geq 0$?

I found out that $A^2 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 3a\\ 0&4 \end{bmatrix}$ and that $A^3 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 7a\\ 0&8 \end{bmatrix}$, which means that my conjecture holds for small $n$. But I do not know how to prove it in general.

Comment: By induction...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In the future please include your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prove this by mathematical induction.

Base:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&a\\0&2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&(2^1-1)a\\0&2^1\end{bmatrix}$$

Induction step:

Suppose $A^n = \begin{bmatrix}1&(2^n-1)a\\0&2^n\end{bmatrix}$. Then $$A^{n + 1} = A^nA = \begin{bmatrix}1&(2^n-1)a\\0&2^n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&a\\0&2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&a + 2(2^n-1)a\\0&2^{n + 1}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&(2^{n+1}-1)a\\0&2^{n+1}\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: The idea behind this proof is that the expression holds true for n=1, and for every n that it holds true, it still does for n+1. Therefore the expression is valid for n=1, therefore for n=2, therefore for n=3 and so on...

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$A^n=\left(
I+
\begin{bmatrix}0&a\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
\right)^n=I+\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\begin{bmatrix}0&a\\0&1\end{bmatrix}^k=
I+(2^n-1)\begin{bmatrix}0&a\\0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&(2^n-1)a\\0&2^n\end{bmatrix}$$
where we used the fact that $\begin{bmatrix}0&a\\0&1\end{bmatrix}^k=\begin{bmatrix}0&a\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}=2^n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

$A$'s characteristic equation is $\lambda^2 -3\lambda +2=0$, whose roots are $1$ and $2$.
Hence, $A^n=B+2^n\cdot C$,where $B$ and $C$ are some matrices that you will find by substituting $n=0$ and $n=1$ into this relation.
Note: This is a method that works for any $2 \times 2$ matrix provided that the computations do not get messy.